# I can't use BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher.UseExtendedAdvertisement in my c# program

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to create a BLE server that emit an advertisement with a custom company id and manufacturer data. The company id work fine and I can send a text buffer in my manufacturer data.
but when I try to enable the UseExtendedAdvertisement, my server won't publish anymore.

[image: my bluetooth version]

As you can see my computer can handle BLE 5.0 so I don't understand why can't I use the extended Advertisement feature

```
 publisher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher();


            //publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add()
            // We need to add some payload to the advertisement. A publisher without any payload
            // or with invalid ones cannot be started. We only need to configure the payload once
            // for any publisher.

            // Add a manufacturer-specific section:
            // First, let create a manufacturer data section
            var manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData();

            // Then, set the company ID for the manufacturer data. Here we picked an unused value: 0xFFFE
            manufacturerData.CompanyId = 0xCA21;

            // Finally set the data payload within the manufacturer-specific section
            // Here, use a 16-bit UUID: 0x1234 -> {0x34, 0x12} (little-endian)
            var writer = new DataWriter();
            string author = "abcefghij";
            // Convert a C# string to a byte array  
            byte[] test = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(author);
            writer.WriteBytes(test);

            // Make sure that the buffer length can fit within an advertisement payload. Otherwise you will get an exception.
            manufacturerData.Data = writer.DetachBuffer();

            // Add the manufacturer data to the advertisement publisher:
            //publisher.UseExtendedAdvertisement = true;
            publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(manufacturerData);
```

Here the code I have to create my BLE server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the hardware is Bluetooth LE 5.0 hardware, this does not mean that all new Bluetooth LE 5.0 functions are supported. Your application should check this via [BluetoothAdapter.IsExtendedAdvertising](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothadapter.isextendedadvertisingsupported?view=winrt-22621#windows-devices-bluetooth-bluetoothadapter-isextendedadvertisingsupported) before it starts using such interfaces.

And as a result of the discussion:
It should also be ensured that the test environment with which one tests one's own software has the necessary functions/features :-)

Comment: I done :
 BluetoothAdapter testt = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine("IsExtendedAdvertisingSupported = " + testt.IsExtendedAdvertisingSupported);

And it gave me :
IsExtendedAdvertisingSupported = True

Comment: "...but when I try to enable the UseExtendedAdvertisement, my server won't publish anymore." Can you elaborate a little on this topic? How do you determine that the server is no longer broadcasting?

Comment: I use nRF connect on my phone, when the useExtended line is commented, everything work fine and i see my BLE serve on nRF, but if i add the line i can't see it anymore on nRF

Comment: And does your mobile phone support "Extended advertisement" according to the nRF Device Information?

Comment: that is that, my phone don't support Extended advertisement, thank you , I'm am going to test on another device